Use or in countifs



Column A
Column B




a
traded


b
online


c
online


a
online



how do i make a code that counts lets say how many "a" is either traded or online
I tried
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "a", B:B, "Traded", B:B, "Online")

and expected 2 but i got 0 instead

There are few ways. One way is-
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"a",B:B,"traded")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"a",B:B,"online")

Good choice would be using QYERY() function. Try-
=QUERY(A:B,"select count(A) where A='a' and B matches 'traded|online' label count(A) ''")



I tried both but it is only counting for the traded and not online, so im getting 1 instead of 2

I shown you screenshot. May be you are missing something. Can you share a sample file link so that I can put formula to your file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ewn3ZHzwcMukO2zO5BICGHiFhxqXOE4BtL281VC2tIw/edit?usp=sharing
i made a copy of the thing im working on above, im working on the code at cell k21

@Clarice You have space after Online  . Either remove that space or use criteria with space. See your sheet query function.

Another way to do it, which is not as clean but might be easier to understand for beginners that come across this, is the following:
=sum(arrayformula(if(A2:A="a", if((--(B2:B="traded")+--(B2:B="online"))>0, 1, 0), 0)))

This formula is based off using IF to find the matching values. When there is a matching value, 1 is returned, and then all the 1s are summed up using SUM.
Note: Using a logical expression like --(A > B) converts TRUE/FALSE to 1/0

Below are the steps I took to build this formula:

First, the values with "a" need to be filtered out.

=IF(A2:A="a", TRUE, FALSE)


Next, if the value is true, we want to check if column B is either "traded" or "online". Within an ARRAYFORMULA, OR or AND statements cannot be used within IF, therefore, we need to use a mathematical expression to find the same thing. We also need to convert TRUE/FALSE values into 1/0 by wrapping our expression with --().

IF((--(B2:B="traded") + --(B2:B="online"))>0, TRUE, FALSE)

=IF(A2:A="a", IF((--(B2:B="traded") + --(B2:B="online"))>0, TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)


Now, lets set the proper TRUE/FALSE values based on the results. If all conditions are true (meaning "a" is either "traded" or "online"), return a value of 1, otherwise 0.

=IF(A2:A="a", IF((--(B2:B="traded") + --(B2:B="online"))>0, 1, 0), 0)


In order to make sure the formula works as expected, we need to wrap the entire formula in ARRAYFORMULA. This tells the formula that we want it to perform these checks for each row within the given range (A2:A and B2:B).

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="a", IF((--(B2:B="traded") + --(B2:B="online"))>0, 1, 0), 0))


Lastly, we want to sum the entire equation. Without SUM, the formula will return a column of data containing either 0 or 1, based on the associated values in columns A and B. To find the total, we need to sum the equation, effectively summing the entire column.

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="a", IF((--(B2:B="traded") + --(B2:B="online"))>0, 1, 0), 0)))

